How to override "SAVE" button from a toolbar in Python?
I'm trying to override the "SAVE" button from a toolbar, but this doesn't work By default, when you press the button, just saves the current figure from the plot, but I want to show a message just to create a PDF Report, and then save this file.
What I tried to do was this, according to a forum PLotSaveFigureOverride. There is not much information about this, but what I did was this, with all the code attached:
#From the toolbar already created, bind this to save_figure itself class to other function created
toolbar.bind("save_figure", N_Save)

#New Save Function
def N_Save(event):
    print("HELLOOOO")
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)

But this doesnt work, Why??
import tkinter

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2
import numpy as np


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))


canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

def N_Save(event):
    print("HELLOOOO")
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)


def on_key_press(event):
    print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)


canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)
toolbar.bind("save_figure", N_Save)


def _quit():
    root.quit()  
    root.destroy()  


button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

tkinter.mainloop()


DId you check out matplotlib hooking in to home/back/forward button events

Yes, i have been trying to do it but looks like that just works for "HOME" and "ARROWS" backend buttons, i tried to connect to a trigger but doesnt work either
